# How to change all file extensions with a makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make, file-extension

I am using bash and trying use a makefile to copy all files in a directory with .ppt to .pdf and then add them all into an archive. This is what I have so far

```
.PHONY: all clean

files = $(wildcard *.ppt)

OBJ = $(patsubst %.pdf, %.ppt, $(wildcard *.ppt))

clean:
        rm -f lectures.tar.gz *.pdf
```

The only makefiles I've made up to this point have been used to compile a program from 1 or 2 source files. Not sure how to approach this

Comment: Oh yeah, and `why` do you want to do it this way? Why not a traditional shell script? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I have already made a shell script that works. This is for homework. I have to create a shell script and a makefile that both do the exact same thing and I dont know what to do with the Makefile

Answer (score 3):

The trick with make is that it starts at the *end*, with what you want to create, and then walks backwards towards the beginning, to see what things have changed.

So, what's at the end: what do you want to produce?  Based on your example we'll infer you want to create a compressed tar file named `lectures.tar.gz`.  So, we'll need a target for that:

```
lectures.tar.gz:
```

What goes into the tar file?  the PDF files, which you've already discovered how to compute into the `OBJ` variable, so those things must be listed as prerequisites of `lectures.tar.gz`:

```
lectures.tar.gz: $(OBJ)
```

What is the recipe for that target?  It should create a tar file with that name, containing all the files.  One way is this:

```
lectures.tar.gz: $(OBJ)
        tar czf lectures.tar.gz $(OBJ)
```

Another way, more generic using [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html), would be:

```
lectures.tar.gz: $(OBJ)
        tar czf $@ $^
```

Now, how do you create the `OBJ` files?  For each one you need to copy it from the `.ppt` version.  Since you're using GNU make (as evidenced by your use of `wildcard` etc. functions) you can use a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html) for this; the pattern is this:

```
%.pdf : %.ppt
        cp $< $@
```

This pattern tells make how to build a file `X.pdf` from any file `X.ppt`, with a `cp` command: in this case the automatic variables `$<` and `$@` are required since you don't know the names.  This is an *implicit* rule because the names aren't explicitly listed, but implied by the pattern.

Now how do you build the `.ppt` files?  You don't, because they're source files, so you're done!